# How can use button to trigger jQuery validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

I have form and I am using jQuery's validation.
It's a test demo.

```
    <script src="../JS/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../JS/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#btns").click(function() {
                if ($("<%=form1.ClientID %>").valid()) {
                    ajaxFunc();//ajax funcion to add email to db
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

            <input id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required />
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
            <input type="button" id="btns" value="btn"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I use **Subimit**, the **cemail** input validate working well(it is showing the validate message and high line the input order).

But when I use **button click** - doesn't show something. How can I get the same effect when I use button onclick function? Thank you for your help!

Comment: it should work - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AJ7jp/1/

Comment: You need to call `.validate()` to initialize the plugin before you can call `.valid()` to test it.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the # in the selector. i.e `$("#<%=form1.ClientID %>")`

```
  $(function() {
        $("#btns").click(function() {
            if ($("#<%=form1.ClientID %>").valid()) {
                ajaxFunc();//ajax funcion to add email to db
            }

        });
    });
```